Not able to install gensim
Code:
import nltk
import numpy as np
import re


import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer


from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds


from gensim.summarization.summarizer import summarize

from summarizer import Summarizer

error: No module named 'gensim.summarization
type here

I tried to install it using !pip install but didn't worked at all

you need to provide:  The command you used to install the library  and the command you are using to run your code. Probably you are running your code from a different environment than the one where you installed the library

Check your gensim version. Is it 4.x? You can find it out by using pip freeze in your environment.
Please check
this question and answer. gensim.summarization submodule is deprecated and removed in 4+ gensim versions (wiki page).
You can try alternative packages, or, if you really want to use gensim.summarization, downgrade to lower versions (3.x should be fine).
